# Prolog company/employee scheduling problem

Tags: prolog, schedule

I have a semi complex shift scheduling problem in prolog.
From what I saw it can be solved with CLF but I am not that familiar and the resources online didn't really help me.

The problem states that the company has **50** employees and that each employee can either work in the morning shift(**M**), the evening shift(**E**), the night shift(**N**) or have a rest day(**R**).
The problem has 2 constraints: That at least **15** employees must work at the morning shift(**M**), **10** in the evening one(**E**) and 8 in the night one(**N**) and that no employee can work the night shift(**N**) and have a morning shift(**M**) the next day.

It asks to produce a 30 day schedule by satisfying the above constraints and that multiple solutions exist.

What could be some way to approach the problem and how could I implement it using code in prolog?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Homework? If not, don't use Prolog. Use or-tools or something similar. If yes? Well... What did you try? What is available in Prolog? Obviously there is a rather easy SAT-compatible conjunctive normal form formulation. If that scales well depends on how *cardinalities* are expressed.

Comment: Yes it is indeed homework. I tried to think of how to approach the problem but what we've done haven't really covered such complex topics. I can't seem to find how a solution can be found... Any ideas?

Comment: Try first to do a declarative naive solution in Prolog and see if that is good enough (it might be). Those are usually called "generate-and-test" or "brute force" if you need to search on the internet for it.

Comment: Which *resources online didn't really help* you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full solution (using swi-prolog):

```
days_in_month(30).
employees_num(50).


go :-
    days_in_month(Days),
    length(M, Days),
    days(M),
    show_days(M).


days([D1, D2|T]) :-
    two_days(D1, D2),
    (T = [] ; days([D2|T])).


other_day_constraints(D) :-
    day_constraint(10, e, D),
    maplist(rest_if_not_work, D).


day_constraint(Min, Element, Lst) :-
    employees_num(EmpsNum),
    list_has_ge_elements_being(Min, Element, EmpsNum, Lst).


two_days(D1, D2) :-
    % Set the full number of employees, otherwise prevent_double_shift can shorten the list
    employees_num(EmpsNum),
    length(D1, EmpsNum),
    length(D2, EmpsNum),

    % Pass the 2-day constraint first
    day_constraint(8, n, D1),
    prevent_double_shift(D1, D2),
    day_constraint(15, m, D2),
    
    % Remainder of the day constraints
    day_constraint(15, m, D1),
    day_constraint(8, n, D2),

    other_day_constraints(D1),
    other_day_constraints(D2).


prevent_double_shift([], []).
prevent_double_shift([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    (H1 == n -> dif(H2, m) ; true),
    prevent_double_shift(T1, T2).


rest_if_not_work(E) :-
    (var(E) -> E = r ; true).


show_days([]).
show_days([D|T]) :-
    show_day(D),
    show_days(T).


show_day(D) :-
    forall(member(E, D), (upcase_atom(E, U), write(U))),
    nl.


list_has_ge_elements_being(Min, Elem, MaxLen, L) :-
    list_has_ge_elements_being_(L, Min, Elem, MaxLen).

list_has_ge_elements_being_(L, Min, Elem, Min) :-
    !,
    length(L, Min),
    maplist(=(Elem), L).
list_has_ge_elements_being_(_L, 0, _Elem, _MaxLen).
list_has_ge_elements_being_([H|T], Min, Elem, MaxLen) :-
    Min @> 0,
    MaxLen @> Min,
    (   H = Elem,
        Min0 is Min - 1
    ;   Min0 = Min
    ),
    MaxLen0 is MaxLen - 1,
    list_has_ge_elements_being_(T, Min0, Elem, MaxLen0).
```